# Json parsing in Ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I have to parse the output of the following command:

```
mongo <dbname> --eval "db.isMaster()"
```

which gives output as follows:

```
 {
    "hosts" : [
        "xxx:<port>",
        "xxx:<port>",
        "xxx:<port>"
    ],
    "setName" : "xxx",
    "setVersion" : xxx,
    "ismaster" : true,
    "secondary" : false,
    "primary" : "xxx",
    "me" : "xxx",
    "electionId" : ObjectId("xxxx"),
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : xxx,
    "maxMessageSizeBytes" : xxxx,
    "maxWriteBatchSize" : xxx,
    "localTime" : ISODate("xxx"),
    "maxWireVersion" : 4,
    "minWireVersion" : 0,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I need to parse the above output to check the value of "ismaster" is true. Please let me know how i can do this in ansible.

At the moment i am simply checking that the text "ismaster" : true is shown in the output using the following code:

```
  tasks:
     - name: Check if the mongo node is primary
       shell: mongo <dbname> --eval "db.isMaster()"
       register: output_text

     - name: Run command on master
       shell: <command to execute>
       when: "'\"ismaster\\\" : true,' in output_text.stdout"
```

However it would be nice to use Ansible's json processing to check the same. Please advise.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There are quite a bit of helpful [filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json) in Ansible.

Try: `when: (output_text.stdout | from_json).ismaster`

Comment: Getting this error when i try to do this: 
"The conditional check '(output_text.stdout | from_json).ismaster' failed. The error was: No JSON object could be decoded\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'xxxx': line xx, column x, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n     - name: Run command on master\n       ^ here\n"}

Comment: Ouch... you have not pure JSON stuff like `ObjectId()` and `ISODate()`. Not sure there is an easy fix for this.

Comment: Have used a this command instead which outputs a "true". mongo <dbname> --eval "db.isMaster().ismaster". Thanks for guiding.

Answer (score 0):

Brother Coder, honestly I got a better Method, because for 3 weeks I just could not parse it with ansible filters as it was to complicated and never worked. I just curled the FILE and used JQ parser with regex. The only thing that is required is that JQ PARSER has to be installed on the server:

To do it with ANSIBLE:

### Use host prompt to choose the envid in the

### 1. curl file like this:

- name: Get json file
  shell: curl --output file.json -k -O  https://example.tp.com/services/getMasterExtract.php?env_id={{envid}}&product=all&du=all&format=json&resolved=true
  args:
  chdir: /tmp/

---

### 2. Extract the Value:

- name: get value from file
  **shell: cat file.json | jq '.globals.environments.{{envid}}."legacy-claimcenter-hostname"' | sed 's/"//g'**
  args:
  chdir: /tmp/
  register: apiaccountclaims

---

### 3. Register as Variable :

- name: set-fact1
  set_fact:
  claims1:  "{{ apiaccountclaims.stdout }}"

  4. USE IT ANYWHERE:
- name: Enter service tdiapiaccountclaims
  shell: sudo /usr/share/jbossas/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --command='/system-property=tdigi.api.uri.edge.account.claims:add(value={{ claims1 }})'

Here is the playbook:

---

- hosts: "{{ hosts | default('all') }}"
  become: true

  vars_prompt:
       - name: "envid"
         prompt: "Please put env ID"

  tasks:

  ```
   - name: Get json file
     shell: curl --output file.json -k -O  https://example.tp.com/services/getMasterExtract.php?env_id={{envid}}&product=all&du=all&format=json&resolved=true
     args:
       chdir: /tmp/



   - name: get value from file
     shell: cat file.json | jq '.globals.environments.{{envid}}."legacy-claimcenter-hostname"' | sed 's/"//g'
     args:
       chdir: /tmp/
     register: tdiapiaccountclaims



   - name: set-fact1
     set_fact:
       claims1:  "{{ apiaccountclaims.stdout }}"


   - name: copy command file
     copy:
      src:  "cli/systemprops2-2.cli"
      dest: "/opt/jboss/profiles/{{jboss_profile}}/configuration/"

   - name: backup standalone-full.xml
     shell:  cp "/opt/jboss/profiles/{{jboss_profile}}/configuration/standalone-full.xml" "/opt/jboss/profiles/{{jboss_profile}}/configuration/standalone-full.xml.backup.old"

   - name: Delete Configs in file of standalone-full.xml
     shell:  sudo /usr/share/jbossas/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --file=systemprops2-2.cli
     args:
       chdir: /opt/jboss/profiles/{{ jboss_profile }}/configuration
     register: delvar


   - name: Enter service tdiapiaccountclaims
     shell: sudo /usr/share/jbossas/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --command='/system-property=tdigi.api.uri.edge.account.claims:add(value={{ claims1 }})'
  ```

Comment: My 2 cents: Usually, at least from my point of view, using the shell module means you are not doing it right...