# using ansible to parse api return

Tags: ansible

I'm terribly stuck for 2 days on this.  I have the below list from an api and want to print from tower with something more readable for the enduser.  It should be something like a list of switches(infraAccPortP.attributes.name) and if there is a children list then a dict with key of infraHPortS.attributes.name and value infraPortBlk.attributes.fromPort
this is my first attempt at using ansible to retrieve data and manipulate it, I usually just use it to build stuff...thats easier it seems

```
    "result.imdata": [
        {
            "infraAccPortP": {
                "attributes": {
                    "annotation": "",
                    "childAction": "",
                    "descr": "",
                    "dn": "uni/infra/accportprof-101_102",
                    "extMngdBy": "",
                    "lcOwn": "local",
                    "modTs": "2020-09-10T14:18:01.362+00:00",
                    "monPolDn": "uni/fabric/monfab-default",
                    "name": "101_102",
                    "nameAlias": "",
                    "ownerKey": "",
                    "ownerTag": "",
                    "status": "",
                    "uid": "15374"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "infraAccPortP": {
                "attributes": {
                    "annotation": "",
                    "childAction": "",
                    "descr": "",
                    "dn": "uni/infra/accportprof-101",
                    "extMngdBy": "",
                    "lcOwn": "local",
                    "modTs": "2020-09-10T14:18:01.775+00:00",
                    "monPolDn": "uni/fabric/monfab-default",
                    "name": "101",
                    "nameAlias": "",
                    "ownerKey": "",
                    "ownerTag": "",
                    "status": "",
                    "uid": "15374"
                },
                "children": [
                    {
                        "infraHPortS": {
                            "attributes": {
                                "annotation": "",
                                "childAction": "",
                                "descr": "",
                                "extMngdBy": "",
                                "lcOwn": "local",
                                "modTs": "2020-09-16T23:09:40.856+00:00",
                                "monPolDn": "uni/fabric/monfab-default",
                                "name": "test",
                                "nameAlias": "",
                                "ownerKey": "",
                                "ownerTag": "",
                                "rn": "hports-test-typ-range",
                                "status": "",
                                "type": "range",
                                "uid": "23110"
                            },
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "infraPortBlk": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "annotation": "",
                                            "childAction": "",
                                            "descr": "",
                                            "extMngdBy": "",
                                            "fromCard": "1",
                                            "fromPort": "12",
                                            "lcOwn": "local",
                                            "modTs": "2020-09-16T23:09:40.856+00:00",
                                            "monPolDn": "uni/fabric/monfab-default",
                                            "name": "block2",
                                            "nameAlias": "",
                                            "rn": "portblk-block2",
                                            "status": "",
                                            "toCard": "1",
                                            "toPort": "12",
                                            "uid": "23110"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "infraHPortS": {
                            "attributes": {
                                "annotation": "",
                                "childAction": "",
                                "descr": "",
                                "extMngdBy": "",
                                "lcOwn": "local",
                                "modTs": "2020-09-16T13:33:07.108+00:00",
                                "monPolDn": "uni/fabric/monfab-default",
                                "name": "101_fex",
                                "nameAlias": "",
                                "ownerKey": "",
                                "ownerTag": "",
                                "rn": "hports-101_fex-typ-range",
                                "status": "",
                                "type": "range",
                                "uid": "23110"
                            },
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "infraRsAccBaseGrp": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "annotation": "",
                                            "childAction": "",
                                            "extMngdBy": "",
                                            "fexId": "101",
                                            "forceResolve": "yes",
                                            "lcOwn": "local",
                                            "modTs": "2020-09-16T13:33:07.108+00:00",
                                            "monPolDn": "uni/fabric/monfab-default",
                                            "rType": "mo",
                                            "rn": "rsaccBaseGrp",
                                            "state": "formed",
                                            "stateQual": "none",
                                            "status": "",
                                            "tCl": "infraFexBndlGrp",
                                            "tDn": "uni/infra/fexprof-101_fex/fexbundle-101_fex",
                                            "tType": "mo",
                                            "uid": "23110"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "infraAccPortP": {
                "attributes": {
                    "annotation": "",
                    "childAction": "",
                    "descr": "",
                    "dn": "uni/infra/accportprof-102",
                    "extMngdBy": "",
                    "lcOwn": "local",
                    "modTs": "2020-09-10T14:18:02.163+00:00",
                    "monPolDn": "uni/fabric/monfab-default",
                    "name": "102",
                    "nameAlias": "",
                    "ownerKey": "",
                    "ownerTag": "",
                    "status": "",
                    "uid": "15374"
                },
                "children": [
                    {
                        "infraHPortS": {
                            "attributes": {
                                "annotation": "",
                                "childAction": "",
                                "descr": "",
                                "extMngdBy": "",
                                "lcOwn": "local",
                                "modTs": "2020-09-16T18:30:37.333+00:00",
                                "monPolDn": "uni/fabric/monfab-default",
                                "name": "test",
                                "nameAlias": "",
                                "ownerKey": "",
                                "ownerTag": "",
                                "rn": "hports-test-typ-range",
                                "status": "",
                                "type": "range",
                                "uid": "23110"
                            },
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "infraPortBlk": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "annotation": "",
                                            "childAction": "",
                                            "descr": "",
                                            "extMngdBy": "",
                                            "fromCard": "1",
                                            "fromPort": "7",
                                            "lcOwn": "local",
                                            "modTs": "2020-09-16T18:30:37.333+00:00",
                                            "monPolDn": "uni/fabric/monfab-default",
                                            "name": "block2",
                                            "nameAlias": "",
                                            "rn": "portblk-block2",
                                            "status": "",
                                            "toCard": "1",
                                            "toPort": "7",
                                            "uid": "23110"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "infraHPortS": {
                            "attributes": {
                                "annotation": "",
                                "childAction": "",
                                "descr": "",
                                "extMngdBy": "",
                                "lcOwn": "local",
                                "modTs": "2020-09-11T15:26:44.501+00:00",
                                "monPolDn": "uni/fabric/monfab-default",
                                "name": "9k_b25b_1-32",
                                "nameAlias": "",
                                "ownerKey": "",
                                "ownerTag": "",
                                "rn": "hports-9k_b25b_1-32-typ-range",
                                "status": "",
                                "type": "range",
                                "uid": "23110"
                            },
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "infraPortBlk": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "annotation": "",
                                            "childAction": "",
                                            "descr": "",
                                            "extMngdBy": "",
                                            "fromCard": "1",
                                            "fromPort": "48",
                                            "lcOwn": "local",
                                            "modTs": "2020-09-11T15:26:44.501+00:00",
                                            "monPolDn": "uni/fabric/monfab-default",
                                            "name": "block2",
                                            "nameAlias": "",
                                            "rn": "portblk-block2",
                                            "status": "",
                                            "toCard": "1",
                                            "toPort": "48",
                                            "uid": "23110"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected results would look something like:

```
   switch:  101
     ports:
     - srvName: test 
       port: 12
     - srvName: test2
       port:13
   switch: 102
     ports:
     - srvName: test3
       port: 12
     - srvName: test4
       port:13
```

Comment: Ansible exposes a set of filters to work with different types of data — one of them being the `from_json` filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844720/json-parsing-in-ansible

Comment: `I'm terribly stuck for 2 days on this [...] this is my first attempt at using ansible to retrieve data and manipulate it` => Please share what you have tried and what is your exact problem to achieve your result.

Comment: There are "children of children". Add the expected result.

Comment: I tried creating a jinja2 template then using the lookup('template') function to print to output.  then I tried using a few set_fact with map(attribute="").  that started to work but it was getting complicated.  When things get hard to understand by the guy writing them its time to find another way. lol.  thats a new filter that I haven't used before so I'll try that and get back with you on the results.  thanks

Comment: The expected result is not a valid YAML. It looks like a dictionary, but 1) the root key is missing, 2) other keys are not unique, and 3) the indentation is wrong. Should it be a list of dictionaries? Make it a valid [YAML](http://www.yamllint.com/)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: *"List of switches(infraAccPortP.attributes.name)"*

A: The task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.imdata|json_query('[].*.*.name')|flatten }}"
```

gives

```
  msg:
  - '101_102'
  - '101'
  - '102'
```

Comment: rock on. json_query was the filter I was missing

Comment: See [Multiselect Hash](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#multiselect-hash).

Comment: to close out this discussion.  json_query or parsing json is the way to go.  using Multiselect you are able to create a new data structure from the existing one.  simple tutorial and syntax tester [link](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)