# how to iterate over list from json in ansible

Tags: json, loops, ansible

I tried to register an output to a variable, but i couldnt filter the way i want it.

output:

```
oc get hpa -o json |jq -r '.items[].spec'
    {
      "maxReplicas": 3,
      "minReplicas": 1,
      "scaleTargetRef": {
        "apiVersion": "apps.openshift.io/v1",
        "kind": "DeploymentConfig",
        "name": "hello-openshift"
      },
      "targetCPUUtilizationPercentage": 70
    }
    {
      "maxReplicas": 4,
      "minReplicas": 2,
      "scaleTargetRef": {
        "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
        "kind": "Deployment",
        "name": "testrhel"
      },
      "targetCPUUtilizationPercentage": 79
    }
```

Register the output to variable

```
- name: check for existing
  shell: oc get hpa -o json |jq -r '.items[].spec'
  register: existing
```

I would like to loop the output.name and compare it to another variable.

```
- name: set_fact
  exist: {% if item.name == newvar and item.kind == newvar2 %}yes{%else%}no{%endif%}
  loop:
    - "{{ existing }}" 

- name: task
  shell: do something
  when: exist == yes
```

Thanks in advance.

**edit:**
currently i am using below to get my comparison for the variables.

```
- name: Get existing hpa output
  shell: oc get hpa -o json -n {{ namespace }} |jq -r '.'
  register: tempvar
      
- name: set hpa variable to fact
  set_fact:
  existing_deploy: "{{ tempvar.stdout}}"

- name: Comparing existing hpa to new config
  set_fact:
    hpa_exist: "{% if deploy_type == item.spec.scaleTargetRef.kind|lower and deploy_name == item.spec.scaleTargetRef.name|lower %}yes{% else %}no{% endif %}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ existing_deploy['items'] }}"
```

but the variable got overwrite when i trying to use when condition

```
- name: task a
  include_tasks: a.yml
  when: hpa_exist
    
- name: task b
  include_tasks: b.yml
  when: not hpa_exist
```

deploymentconfig/hello-openshift condition always fail even when it is true. leading to execute task b, which is not supposed to

Comment: Did you debug the content of `existing` to look at its exact structure/content and then try to use it accordingly ? Hint: Since your are registering from shell, it will contain a `existing.stdout` entry which probably contains the exact data you're looking for. Hint2: ansible has a `from_json` filter to parse text representation of json. Hint3: your actual output is not valid json.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#return-values) of the `shell` module.
The output of the shell on `stdout` will be in `<var>.stdout` (so in `existing.stdout` in your case.)

Once you got that, you obviously have `json` as text, but you want to parse it. To do that, use the `from_json` filter as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40844916/3683639).

Summa summarum your task should look like this:

```yaml
- name: set_fact
  set_fact:
    exist: {% if item['scaleTargetRef']['name'] == newvar and item['scaleTargetRef']['kind']  == newvar2 %}yes{% else %}no{% endif %}
  loop: "{{ existing.stdout | from_json}}"
```

But your output needs to be a valid list, so basically, it needs to look like this:

```json
    [{
      "maxReplicas": 3,
      "minReplicas": 1,
      "scaleTargetRef": {
        "apiVersion": "apps.openshift.io/v1",
        "kind": "DeploymentConfig",
        "name": "hello-openshift"
      },
      "targetCPUUtilizationPercentage": 70
    },
    {
      "maxReplicas": 4,
      "minReplicas": 2,
      "scaleTargetRef": {
        "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
        "kind": "Deployment",
        "name": "testrhel"
      },
      "targetCPUUtilizationPercentage": 79
    }]
```

But you might actually have a logic error, because you are looping over the list and overwriting the variable `exist` on every turn. So you will end up with one variable `exist` in the end and that will hold the value of the last iteration.
Check out how to [register variables with a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop) if you need the output of every iteration.

If you want to do something for each item that meets the condition, you can do this:

```yaml
- name: check for existing
  shell: oc get hpa -o json | jq -r '.items[].spec'
  register: existing

- name: include tasks a
  include_tasks: a.yml
  when:
    - deploy_type == item['scaleTargetRef']['kind'] | lower
    - deploy_name == item['scaleTargetRef']['name'] | lower
  loop: "{{  existing.stdout | from_json }}"

- name: include tasks b
  include_tasks: b.yml
  when: (deploy_type != item['scaleTargetRef']['kind'] | lower) or
        (deploy_name != item['scaleTargetRef']['name'] | lower)
  loop: "{{  existing.stdout | from_json }}"
```

You do not need any of the `set_fact` stuff in that case.

Comment: A better "ansiblich" way to write the expression IMO: `exist: "{{ ((item['scaleTargetRef']['name'] == newvar) and (item['scaleTargetRef']['kind']  == newvar2)) | bool }}"`

Comment: Thanks, and i do face the issue you mentioned where the last iteration always overwrite. I have been reading the link and tested but still cant achieve what i want to do.
i wanted to do 

`shell: something
when: exist`

`shell: something else
when: not exist`

Comment: @sloweriang check out my last edit, does that help you?

Comment: soory no , i am just getting more confuse.

see my edit ..currently i m using set_fact: var.stdout
but i still getting the variable overwrite by the last iteration

Comment: @sloweriang I modified the last example based on your edit. You need to parse the json and you need to do the import for every item in the list, so you need a loop at the import statement. The last edit will potentially import the tasks multiple times if there are multiple items in the list that match the same condition. I don't really get what you want to do, so no idea if that is an issue.

Comment: I followed your last modified but failed with `raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` when using `|from_json`

Comment: anyway, my current issue is , i am able to compare the variable but it always got overwritten.
if i following the code you provided, it will fail instead of skip

Comment: @sloweriang What error do you get? It works for me. Please make sure the JSON output you get is actually valid JSON. The output you posted in your question is not. It needs to be a list of dicts as shown in the answer. Invalid JSON is probably the reason for  `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`.